# Partitioning a vector of objects into 2 or more subgroups

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to partition a vector of references to `MyObject` (i.e. `vector<MyObject*>`) into 2 or more sub-vectors based on some common traits.

I have an equivalence function `bool belongToSameGroup(MyObject *x, MyObject *y);` which is `true` if certain data fields of `MyObject` are equal, and `false` otherwise. Because this equivalence is not general and for a particular purpose only, I'd prefer not to overload `operator==`.

What is the best way I can create, say, a vector of `<vector<MyObject*>`'s (i.e. `vector< vector<MyObject*> >`) such that the elements are grouped based on their eqivalence under the function `belongToSameGroup`? I'd prefer not to do a bunch of `for` loops and to utilize STL algorithms and containers as much as possible.

Comment: Have you tried `std::partition`? Is it necessary that they be separate vectors or are simple iterator ranges okay?

Comment: @Billy: Change that to an answer so I can up-vote it!

Comment: @jwismar: Okay, done. However, I still would like to know if iterator ranges are okay. `std::partition` will give you one vector partitioned into two ranges. If they don't have to be separate vectors you're done; if they do you'd probably be better off using something like `copy_if`.

Comment: Note: I really hope you're not sticking raw pointers in vectors when `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` are available

Comment: Is it possible to define order that is compatible with belongToSameGroup? If so, you can define lessThen(x,y), and use is in multiset: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/. Insert all objects to it and then retrieve elements with http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/equal_range/ but, may be loops are better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `std::partition` is what you want. (Hey, it's even in the title of your question!)

Comment: More specifically, you would want to bind (e.g. `bind1st`) the first element of the array to the first argument of `belongToSameGroup`, and call `partition` iteratively on the second subset to produce more subsets.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: True -- if you need more criteria you could do a partition for the first thing to look for, then do another partition on the remaining set, etc. Just use the iterator returned by `std::partition` as the argument for another round of `std:: partition`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::remove_copy_if` along with a back insert iterator for a `std::vector<MyObject*>`.  So that would look like (where TESTFUNCTION is your function that takes a type `MyObject*` and returns a `bool`):

```
std::vector<MyObject*> original;

std::vector<MyObject*> partion_A;
std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<MyObject*> > inserter_A(partion_A);

std::remove_copy_if(original.begin(), original.end(), inserter_A, TESTFUNCTION);
```

Now `partition_A` will contain all values where TESTFUNCTION is true.  If you want a second partion vector `partion_B`, simply make another TESTFUNCTION_B that tests for the opposite condition, as well as another back inserter `inserter_B` that is initialized with the value of `partion_B`.

Two advantages of this method compared to `std::partition` are 1) it does not change the original vector so there are most likely more scenarios it an be used (i.e., situations involving constant iterators), and 2) It can be run on containers that do not have bidirectional iterators like `std::list`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a bunch of `for` loops, you just need to run `std::for_each` on your vector and decide what to do with each element. Or use `std::partition` if you can leave them in the same container, just reorganized.

---

As mentioned in the comments - in the C++ 11 standard, `for` supports the functionality previously requiring the `std::for_each`.

Comment: for_each and for  aren't much different.

Comment: @nishantjr no, and in C++11 `for` syntax includes the functionality formerly implemented through `std::for_each`. How languages evolve...

Comment: Hmm. I was not downvoting to make myself feel good, or to put you down, just to improve the experience for the next reader. At the algorithmic level, they aren't different. (Sorry, can't repeal the downvote though.)